# Is it more efficient to declare the length of array before assigning values at its indices?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there any benefit to setting the array's length before assigning values?

For example,

```
let arr = [];
arr.length = 10;
arr[0] = 'a'; // arr.length === 10
...
arr[9] = 'i'; // arr.length === 10
```

or even

```
let arr = new Array(10);
arr[0] = 'a'; // arr.length === 10
...
arr[9] = 'i'; // arr.length === 10
```

versus

```
let arr = [];
arr[0] = 'a'; // arr.length === 1
arr[1] = 'b'; // arr.length === 2
...
arr[9] = 'i'; // arr.length === 10
```

Comment: Also https://jsperf.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In V8, at least, it would appear that `new Array(length)` is much faster than the alternatives, by at least an order of magnitude. Including the `push` method just for fun:

(warning: running the following code will *block* your browser for a bit)

```js
const t0 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 2e6; i++) {
  const arr = [];
  arr.length = 7;
  arr[0] = 'a';
  arr[1] = 'b';
  arr[2] = 'c'
  arr[3] = 'd'
  arr[4] = 'e'
  arr[5] = 'f';
  arr[6] = 'g';
}
const t1 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 2e6; i++) {
  const arr = new Array(7);
  arr[0] = 'a';
  arr[1] = 'b';
  arr[2] = 'c'
  arr[3] = 'd'
  arr[4] = 'e'
  arr[5] = 'f';
  arr[6] = 'g';
}
const t2 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 2e6; i++) {
  const arr = [];
  arr[0] = 'a';
  arr[1] = 'b';
  arr[2] = 'c'
  arr[3] = 'd'
  arr[4] = 'e'
  arr[5] = 'f';
  arr[6] = 'g';
}
const t3 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 2e6; i++) {
  const arr = [];
  arr.push('a');
  arr.push('b');
  arr.push('c');
  arr.push('d');
  arr.push('e');
  arr.push('f');
  arr.push('g');
}
const t4 = performance.now();

console.log('arr.length = length', t1 - t0);
console.log('new Array(length)', t2 - t1);
console.log('arr = [] only', t3 - t2);
console.log('push only', t4 - t3);
```

The difference is less impressive on Firefox, but it's still there - `new Array(length)` appears to be something like twice as fast as the other possibilities. You might think that

```
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
```

would be even more efficient, which is true in FF (by another couple orders of magnitude) but it would appear to be *about the same* as `new Array(length)` in V8:

```js
const t0 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 2e8; i++) {
  const arr = new Array(7);
  arr[0] = 'a';
  arr[1] = 'b';
  arr[2] = 'c'
  arr[3] = 'd'
  arr[4] = 'e'
  arr[5] = 'f';
  arr[6] = 'g';
}
const t1 = performance.now();
for (let i = 0; i < 2e8; i++) {
  const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
}
const t2 = performance.now();

console.log('new Array(length)', t1 - t0);
console.log(`arr = ['a', 'b', ...]`, t2 - t1);
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why setting `arr.length` is relatively slow compared to the others? And why `new Array(length)` is relatively fast compared to the others? Also, in Chrome,  the `new Array()` test takes 5ms on my PC, and in Edge it takes about 150ms.

Comment: When you do `arr = []`, the interpreter initializes an empty array with length 0. If, on the next step, you do `arr.length = 7`, it has to *go back and change* that empty array's `length` property to 7 - it makes sense that that takes a bit longer, because it's 2 steps instead of 1. (maybe a compiler would eventually be smart enough to to optimize that into one step only, but we're not there yet)

Comment: When you assign to an arrays index, like `arr[0] = 'a'` or with `push`, that will require changing the array's `length` property *if the array's `length` is not already 1+*. So I would guess that since `new Array(length)` doesn't require changing the `length` property every time an item is added, it's the fastest. The `arr.length = 7` method requires setting the length *twice* (once on initialization, then once on the next line), so it takes longer, makes sense

Comment: I'm a bit confused on why it only changes the length property "if the array's length is not already 1+". When using `arr.length = length`, that sets the length just once; when setting `arr[0] = 'a'; arr[1] = 'b'; ...`, does that not set the length each time you add a new item? (similar with push). In the test, `arr.length = length 292.49999998137355` is slower than `arr = [] only 63.10000002849847`, which doesn't really make sense to me, so I am still misunderstanding something.

Comment: Oh, that's right, the `arr.length =` method takes the *longest* in V8, by a significant margin. Huh, that does seem quite strange, I would've expected it to take a bit more time than the `new Array(length)` method. Poked around some, but I don't know, and I don't know enough about V8 internals to understand why, sorry

Comment: Thats alright. Thanks for the answer though. Most importantly, it seems like `new Array()` is the way to go in terms of efficiency.